# "Hug me as tightly as how much you love me" Is this correct?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

> "Hug me as tightly as how much you love me."
>
> "Hug me as tightly as you love me."
>
> "Hug me as much tightly as you love me."

Which is correct? Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Sentence one is correct and describes exactly what you mean, but it is awkward because of it.

Sentence two is also correct, and flows better because the "how much" is clearly implied.

Sentence three in not correct because you're using the adverb "tightly" to modify the quantity "as much", which is not a verb.

Answer (score 0):

"Hug me as much as you love me" or "Hug me and show how much you love me".

Comment: Wouldn't "Hug me as much as you love me" imply "Hug me more often"?

Comment: Also, there's no way I can use an adverb together with "as much as~"? Thanks so much!

Comment: Question #1: No, it means "Show me how much you love me by hugging me.".
Question #2: No, only a noun. "I can eat as much food as I want" or "She is taking as much time as needed to finish the task."

Note: I did not use "tightly" as it would be redundant. "Hug" means to hold tightly.

Comment: @xoxo_s To express hugging someone with greater frequency, you would need to say *hug me as **often** as you love me.* Note, however, that all of these sentences equate two things of different types and require poetic interpretation. (There is no actual way of determining exactly *how much* somebody loves someone else—or of figuring out how that translates to tightness or frequency of hugs on anything other than a *relative* scale.)

Comment: @JasonBassford "hug me as often as you love me"? Love isn't measured in terms of frequency. You either love or you don't, it's not a matter of how often.